# How to make socket connection with received IP address and port number

Tags: c, sockets

How do I use inet_addr() to assign an IP address with the variables a, b,c and d
so that I can send the data:

```
a=rcvsdheader->Option.IPv4Address>>24;
//printf("the msb of ipv4 is %d\n",a);
b=rcvsdheader->Option.IPv4Address>>16&0x000000FF;
//printf("the msb of ipv4 is %d\n",b);
c=rcvsdheader->Option.IPv4Address>>8&0x000000FF;
//printf("the msb of ipv4 is %d\n",c);
d=rcvsdheader->Option.IPv4Address&0x000000FF;
//printf("the msb of ipv4 is %d\n",d);
if(rcvsdheader->Option.Protocol==UDP)
printf("The Type of Protocol is UDP\n");
printf("The PortNumber i%d\n",rcvsdheader->Option.Portnumber);
e=rcvsdheader->Option.Portnumber;
if ( (s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
{
    die("socket");
}

someipServeraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
someipServeraddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr();
someipServeraddr.sin_port = htons(e);
```

Comment: `someipServeraddr.sin_addr.s_addr` is an `uint32_t` on POSIX, just assign your IPv4 address to `someipServeraddr.sin_addr.s_addr`, `htonl`ed.

Comment: Dear Haapala I want to pass to variables a,b,c and d to inet_addr() function

Answer (score 1):

`inet_addr` takes a string containing the textual representation of IPv4 address as a parameter:

```
in_addr_t inet_addr(const char *cp);
```

> The  `inet_addr()`  function converts the Internet host address cp from **IPv4 numbers-and-dots notation into binary data in network byte order**.  If the input is invalid, `INADDR_NONE` (usually `-1`)
>          is returned.  Use of this function is problematic because -1 is a valid address (255.255.255.255).  Avoid its use in favor of `inet_aton()`, `inet_pton(3)`, or  `getaddrinfo(3)`,  which  provide  a
>          cleaner way to indicate error return.

Thus, we can use `sprintf` to make one:

```
char buf[16];
sprintf(buf, "%u.%u.%u.%u", a, b, c, d);
someipServeraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(buf);
```

However all this is pointless. `s_addr` is of type `in_addr_t` which is a `typedef` for an `uint32_t` on POSIX, so you can use `rcvsdheader->Option.IPv4Address` directly:

```
someipServeraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(rcvsdheader->Option.IPv4Address);
```

(`htonl` is needed if `IPv4Address` contains the address in *host byte order*, e.g. loop-back as integer `0x7F000001`; if you know your address is in network-order, do not use `htonl`).

Comment: Thank you Haapala.It is working well I choose the sprintf because buf is required in another function in my code

Comment: @YallamandaDosakayala then you might consider [accepting my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#)

Comment: Dear Haapala Do u know anything about automotive protocols like CAN or MOST or socket programming with threads,if u know can u plz guide me as i am doing a project on a new automotive protocol

Comment: I do, but if you have another question to ask, you should post another question.

Comment: Porting my c code (developed on Linux platform) to micrium OS I want to port simple hello world program cross compile to micrium os